# how to find duplicate field in subdocument array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find a way to find and remove duplicate object with the same field in a subdocument array.

Basically my collection has this schema.

```
[{
  "_id": ObjectId("578953db976cea724bbdbb60"),
  "units": [{
    "description": "a1"
  }, {
    "description": "b1"
  }, {
    "description": "a1"
  }, {
    "description": "c1"
  }]
}, {
  "_id": ObjectId("578953db976cea724bbdbb61"),
  "units": [{
    "description": "a2"
  }, {
    "description": "b2"
  }, {
    "description": "a2"
  }, {
    "description": "c2"
  }]
}]
```

I simply wish to find and remove duplicate field with the same description.

So for the first, I need to identify "a1" and a2" respectively.

Thanks.

Update (output should be):

```js
[{
  "_id": ObjectId("578953db976cea724bbdbb60"),
  "units": [{
    "description": "a1"
  }, {
    "description": "b1"
  }, {
    "description": "c1"
  }]
}, {
  "_id": ObjectId("578953db976cea724bbdbb61"),
  "units": [{
    "description": "a2"
  }, {
    "description": "b2"
  }, {
    "description": "c2"
  }]
}]
```

Comment: There is a certain vagueness to what you're trying to achieve. When you remove identical objects from documents, from which document should it be removed? It'll be easy if it's from both.

Comment: What is the expected output after you've removed the duplicates?

Comment: @TanKimLoong Yes I want to remove duplicated data from both array.

Comment: Do you always have a single property in your sub-documents? If that yes, the best thing to do is make "units" an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript

```
db.COLLECTION.find().forEach(function(element){
   var descriptions = element.units.map(function(unit){return unit.description;})
   element.units = element.units.filter(function(value, index, array){
       return descriptions.indexOf(value) == index;
   })
   db.save(element);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `$setUnion` should give you what you want.

`db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project : {_id : "$_id", units : {$setUnion: ["$units"]}}}
])`